# "ReferenceError: Must call super..." when passing raw JSX arg to super in derived class

Tags: reactjs, constructor, jsx, super

Trying to run the following in a React app gives the ReferenceError (below). Why? I'm calling `super()`. Is the JSX somehow "accessing 'this'"?

```
class Base {
  constructor(foo) {
    this.foo = foo
  }
}

class Extender extends Base {
  constructor() {
    super(<p>foo</p>)
  }
}
```

```
ReferenceError: Must call super constructor in derived class before accessing 'this' or returning from derived constructor
new Extender
src/Component01.js:29
  26 | 
  27 | class Extender extends Base {
  28 |   constructor() {
> 29 |     super(<p>foo</p>)
  30 |   }
  31 | }
  32 |
```

Whereas the following (which breaks the encapsulation of the first example, so I don't want to do it) runs fine:

```
class Base {
  constructor(foo) {
    this.foo = foo
  }
}

const someJsx = <p>foo</p>
class Extender extends Base {
  constructor() {
    super(someJsx)
  }
}
```

?

Comment: Why are you passing `JSX` instead of `props` in `super` ? I have not seen this before, can you please explain this part if this is valid.

Comment: @PR7 Thanks for looking. These are not react components, just JS objects, so no 'props'. In this case, this would be a kind of 'helper' object. In my actual app, I have a small hierarchy of objects, and in some cases, I want to pass constant data into `super()`; in this case, the data happens to be JSX. I've worked around the problem -- many ways to do it -- but I like the solution with ES6 class syntax best, and I wonder why it doesn't work. I can pass a string literal; I can pass JSX by var. Why not literal JSX?

Comment: Interesting... Can I ask what is the version of React here. I was trying to debug a little bit.

Comment: @PR7 Good question. I have not tried with any other version. I'm on 17.0.2.